# QNetworkReply::finishes with "Unable to write" error

Tags: c++, qt, baidu

I'm trying to upload some file to a remote server using some API (Baidu Net Disk) but i keep getting  `QNetworkReply::UnknownNetworkError` as the error  and `Unable to write` as the error string.
This only happens when uploading a file greater than 4MBs ..but for small files (~ 1 mb) everything is fine.
I'm using `QHttpMultiPart` and `QHttpPart` to upload the file.

First off is there some way i can get  a more details error message than just **Unable to write** .

```
 QString formatedMd5;
// fileChunkSize holds the content of the file divided into segments ..each segment is 4mb or less 
  foreach (auto hash, mFileChuncks) {

    if (hash != mFileChuncks.last()) {
      formatedMd5.append(QString("\"%1\",").arg(
          QCryptographicHash::hash((hash), QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex()));
    } else {
      formatedMd5.append(QString("\"%1\"").arg(
          QCryptographicHash::hash((hash), QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex()));
    }
  }
  qDebug() << "formated md5  " << formatedMd5;


  QString targetData =
      QString("path=/%1&isdir=0&autoinit=1&rtype=3&block_list=[%2]&size=%3")
          .arg(remotePath)
          .arg(formatedMd5)
          .arg(file->size());
  qDebug() << "  target data is" << targetData;
  QNetworkRequest request(QString("http://pan.baidu.com/rest/2.0/xpan/"
                                  "file?method=precreate&access_token=%1")
                              .arg(access_token));
  request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  request.setRawHeader(QByteArray("X-LC-Session"),
                       QString("4yj8b1l5kvo9wiww2st6jdjn3").toUtf8());

  QNetworkReply *mReply = networkManager->post(request, targetData.toUtf8());
  if (mReply) {
    
    connect(mReply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this,
            [=]() { this->finished(mReply); });
  }
}
```

This works well when uploading small files, but fails when uploading larger files....please help me!

I tried cross checking the url parameters... This works well with small files, but failed with large files

Comment: As you're using http you could just capture the traffic using Wireshark to see what's going on

Comment: I used wire shark but I get "new fragment ovelaps old data"..

Comment: Did you read the REST API documentation of the service you use about limitations?

Comment: Yes...they require a large file ( > 4mb)to be divided into segments of size 4mbs..then upload those segments one by one....but even though the file is only 3 mbs...it still fails...it only uploads files of <=1 mb!